Is it true that according to Kabbalah, everything that Yaakov Avinu did, Yosef also has to do, especially in the context of making 12 tribes?
I heard this on a YouTube class from Rabbi Daniel Glatstein that he said that everything that Yaakov Avinu did, Yosef also has to do, especially in the context of making 12 tribes.  I've wanted to find that class to get the source which he provided, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help? It had to do with the Universe of Leah and the Universe of Rochel in Kabbalah.
I also remember from another source that the 12 tribes of Yosef were made up of Efraim, Menashe, and the 10 sons of Binyamin who were all named after yosef, as it says in Rashi.

The source for this idea is in Midrash Tanchuma (Parshas Mikeitz 3) which states:

אַתְּ מוֹצֵא כָּל מַה שֶּׁהִגִּיעַ לְיַעֲקֹב הִגִּיעַ לְיוֹסֵף. יַעֲקֹב נוֹלַד מָהוּל, וְיוֹסֵף כֵּן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: אֵלֶּה תֹּלְדוֹת יַעֲקֹב יוֹסֵף. זֶה נִקְרָא בְּנִי בְכוֹרִי יִשְׂרָאֵל, וְזֶה הַבְּכוֹרָה לְיוֹסֵף. זֶה גָּלָה לְחָרָן, וְזֶה לְמִצְרָיִם. זֶה נִתְרוֹמֵם בַּחֲלוֹם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיַּחֲלֹם וְהִנֵּה סֻלָּם (בראשית כח, כב), וְזֶה וּפַרְעֹה חֹלֵם
Everything that occurred to Jacob likewise happened to Joseph. Jacob was born circumcised, and so too was Joseph, as is said: These are the generations of Jacob, Joseph (Gen. 37:2). The former was called The son of my firstborn, Israel (Exod. 4:22), and the latter was spoken of as the firstborn was Joseph’s (I Chron. 5:2). The former was exiled to Haran, and the latter to Egypt. Jacob was exalted through a dream, as it is said: And He dreamed, and behold, a ladder set upon the earth (Gen. 38:22). Joseph interpreted Pharaoh’s dream.

The last statement you referenced is from the gemara (Sotah 36b):

תַּנְיָא: הָיָה רָאוּי יוֹסֵף לָצֵאת מִמֶּנּוּ שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר שְׁבָטִים כְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁיָּצְאוּ מִיַּעֲקֹב אָבִיו, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אֵלֶּה תֹּלְדוֹת יַעֲקֹב יוֹסֵף״, אֶלָּא שֶׁיָּצָא שִׁכְבַת זַרְעוֹ מִבֵּין צִיפּוֹרְנֵי יָדָיו. וְאַף עַל פִּי כֵן, יָצְאוּ מִבִּנְיָמִין אָחִיו, וְכוּלָּן נִקְרְאוּ עַל שְׁמוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וּבְנֵי בִנְיָמִן בֶּלַע וָבֶכֶר וְאַשְׁבֵּל וְגוֹ׳״.
It is taught in a baraita: Joseph was deserving of having twelve tribes descend from him, the same as twelve tribes descended from his father Jacob, as it is stated: “These are the generations of Jacob, Joseph” (Genesis 37:2). This implies that everything that happened to Jacob was destined to happen to Joseph. However, he did not merit this because his semen was emitted from between his fingernails. And even so, the offspring that were meant to descend from him descended from his brother Benjamin, who had ten sons. And they were all named after Joseph, as it is stated: “And the sons of Benjamin: Bela, and Becher, and Ashbel, Gera, and Naaman, Ehi, and Rosh, Muppim, and Huppim, and Ard” (Genesis 46:21).

